# Conditional sum on multiple pandas groups, each defined by a set of overlapping column values

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to perform a conditional sum on groups of rows defined by a list of arbitrary column values. By conditional sum, I mean sum values in one column only if the value in a second column is above a threshold. There can be overlap among the groups and the number of elements in each group can be different.

For example, given the following dataframe:

```py
data = {
   'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
   'counter': [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
   'output': [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 35, 20, 15, 10, 5]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```
>>> df
   id  counter  output
0   1       10       5
1   2        9      10
2   3        8      15
3   4        7      20
4   5        6      25
5   6        5      35
6   7        4      20
7   8        3      15
8   9        2      10
9  10        1       5
```

And the following inputs (I'm flexible if we need to change their format):

```py
group_ids = {'Group A': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'Group B': [6, 7, 8, 9], 'Group C': [4, 5, 6]}
output_threshold = 12
```

I would like to generate the following new dataframe, which is the sum of `counter` for each group defined by the list of `group_ids` only if `output` exceeds the specified `output_threshold`. Bonus points if I can add the title to each of these groups:

```
title    sum
Group A   15
Group B   12
Group C   18
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `isin` to check for values and sum:

```
mask = (df['output'] > output_threshold).astype(int)
for k,v in group_ids.items():
    df[k] = df['id'].isin(v) * mask * df['counter']

df[group_ids.keys()].sum()
```

Output (can't quite match your expected):

```
Group A    15
Group B    12
Group C    18
dtype: int64
```

Comment: I think this works. Thanks for the fast turn-around! Actually your code caught a bug in my expected values :) Group B should sum to 12, not 7. Fixed it in the question. Just going to run some quick tests and let you know how it goes. Thanks again!

Comment: Alright, everything worked. I just had to wrap the Series returned by sum() with a DataFrame (I had to add more columns) and we're on our way! Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

Working within dictionaries and rebuilding the dataframe could work as well :

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import product
d = defaultdict(list)

#get the product of M and group_ids
for entry, groups in product(M,group_ids.items()):
    #pass in the condition
    if entry['id'] in groups[-1] and entry['output'] > output_threshold:
        #extract relevant counter value
        d[groups[0]].append(entry['counter'])

#sum the list values
d = {k:sum(v) for k,v in d.items()}

#create dataframe
res = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d,orient='index',columns=['Total'])

res

            Total
Group A     15
Group C     18
Group B     12
```

Comment: Interesting approach. What's the benefit of working with dictionaries instead of dataframes? Readability suffers a bit in this case. Is there a performance benefit, or are there certain things you can't do in dataframes?

Comment: if vectorization isn't involved, and u r iterating, dictionaries should offer better performance.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a solution to the question in this post, except for the fact that the `id` groups **CANNOT** be overlapping.

You may want to create an inverse_group dictionary, map the id and groupby:

```py
inverse_groups={x:k for k,v in group_ids.items() for x in v}

(df[df['output']>output_threshold]
   .groupby(df['id'].map(inverse_groups))
   .counter.sum()
)
```

```
Output:

id
Group A     8
Group B     7
Group C    18
Name: counter, dtype: int64
```

> Full credit goes to @QuangHoang. This was his first reply to my question, which he completely re-wrote to satisfy the overlapping `id` condition.